# text inside the mat-progress-bar in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

In the mat-progress-bar  I have to display the text inside the progress-bar not value any other percentage. can any one help to display text inside the progress-bar?

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" class="progress-bar" [color]="color " [value]="progress" ></mat-progress-bar>
```

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365836/how-to-set-text-inside-md-progress-spinner-in-angular-4

Comment: There's another great solution of a [Progress spinner with background and text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52300133/4049371)

Answer (score 5):

You need to create it manually as it is not available in Material 2.x

**Solution:**
You can place the `<md-progress-spinner>` inside a `<div>` and add another `<div>` inside that to display the text and adjust position manually.

```
<div>
<md-progress-spinner [color]="color" 
                     [mode]="mode" 
                     [value]="value" aria-label="Rating" 
                     mode="determinate">
</md-progress-spinner>
<div style="position:relative; top: -60px; left: 30px;">
    {{ showText }}
</div>
```

I hope it resolves your query.

Working example: [This can help you, I found on SO only](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-ojwpb7?file=app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use a div with absolute positioning:

```
<section class="example-section">
      <mat-progress-bar
          [color]="primary"
          [mode]="mode"
          [value]="value">
      </mat-progress-bar>
            <div style="position: absolute; padding: 10px; color: white;"> {{value}}% </div>
    </section>
```

You can create a css class as well for this component

You have to change the height of the progress bar as well:

```
.mat-progress-bar {
  height: 30px;
}
```

and

```
.example-section {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}
```

[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7q6bsg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogress-bar-configurable-example.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use css to do this. This way, your content is **always in the centralized progress bar**. The only condition is the `width` and `height` of the `mat-progress-spinner` being the same as the parent `div`:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
  <mat-progress-spinner style="width: 100px;height: 100px;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;" [color]="'primary'" [mode]="'determinate'" [value]="60">
  </mat-progress-spinner>
  <h1 >69%</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer @user10549656 gave?

Comment: @SmrtGrunt in his solution the content was centralized manually using top and left attributes. so if the size of the content changes, maybe it will leave the center.

Comment: Got it. Please make sure that distinction is captured in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can configure with the existing material progress bar, you need to come up with your own way of implementing it by adding a div with your custom style as follows,

```
<mat-progress-spinner
        class="example-margin"
        [color]="color"
        [mode]="mode"
        [value]="value">        
    </mat-progress-spinner>
    <div style="position:relative; top: -60px; left: 30px;"> Loading </div>
 </mat-card-content>
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkj61s?file=app/progress-spinner-configurable-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

To insert the center progress bar use the following attributes **`width: 100%; text-align: center;`** inside the div

```
<div style="position: absolute; padding: 10px; color: white; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
```